# Should I take precautions when using different CAN transceivers on the same bus?

Tags: can, bus, transceiver

What are the precautions I should be aware of when using different transceivers on a CAN bus?

What I can think of:

- They neeed to operate at the same voltage (on `CAN_H` and `CAN_L`)
- They need to have some common baudrates (at least one)

Is there anything else?

For example I would like to use both these transceivers on the same CAN bus:

- [MCP2551](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/21667e.pdf)
- [SN65HVD230](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn65hvd230.pdf)

Comment: As it happens I use exactly those 2 on the same buses all the time. Microchip has a newer part MCP2561 which is pin compatible though, just better.

Comment: I'm doing CAN for a hobby project and the MCP2551 is easier to find and a little bit cheaper. You are right to point that Microchip recommends to use the MCP2561 instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole reason why we have such standards / specifications as CAN bus is to eliminate / avoid the potential issues you mention.

The transceivers simply need to adhere to the [CAN bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus) specification which they do as both transceivers meet the ISO-11898 standard physical layer requirements, i.e. CAN bus. This specifies the voltages on CAN_H and CAN_L so no need to worry about that.

It is up to you (the user) to configure the speed of the transceivers in such a way that both can work together. For example a device might not support the same data rates as the other device. It is up to you to select the data rate which all transceivers support.